# Send multiple emails simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, quartz.net

I have a WebApi project with a list of scheduled emails using Quartz.Net (embedded, not Windows service) which scheduled daily at 9 am. I want it to be simultaneously. Therefore I added `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

```
public override async Task ExecuteJob(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>  EmailHelper.SendEmailAsync("reminder",user.email));
    }
}
```

However, the Job ran, but it doesn't send an email if I enabled `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Any alternative way to send email simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SendEmailAsync` returns a `Task` derived result, use `Task.WhenAll` to run all the tasks together.

```
public override Task ExecuteJob(IJobExecutionContext context) {
    var tasks = users.Select(user => EmailHelper.SendEmailAsync("reminder", user.email));
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Since nothing is actually being awaited in the function there is no need to tag it with async. Just return the task.